# Cannot find the sample_image for imagepyramid in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

The latest geoserver (2.17.1) with extension imagepyramid is looking for sample_image for each layer in the pyramid retile file.

The warning message:

```
29 Jun 15:39:32 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path /mosaic/5/sample_image
29 Jun 15:39:32 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path file:/mosaic/5/5.shp
29 Jun 15:39:34 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path /mosaic/4/sample_image
29 Jun 15:39:34 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path file:/mosaic/4/4.shp
29 Jun 15:39:37 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path /mosaic/3/sample_image
29 Jun 15:39:37 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to find sample image for path file:/mosaic/3/3.shp
```

Could I force geoserver to ignore the sample_image or how to create it?

Comment: how did you create your pyramid? Does the user running GeoServer got write permission to the pyramid directory so it can create a sample image? Does something not work now?

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for your reply. I use my own script to generate the pyramid in parallel (the same results of geo_retile). I have give the write permission to the pyramid directory. It is working to process request in OpenLayers, but take a few seconds to find the sample_image in some request.

Comment: @Bangyou Any update for your problem?